# Rails form with nested resource is generating a nil output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-resources

I am creating a form for adding suggestions to suggestion boxes.  However, while I am able to submit the form successfully and rails returns a flash message that the suggestion was submitted successfully, the value for the suggestion message is nil.

I have reviewed the various other posts on forms with nested resources but nothing has helped in allowing me to solve the problem.

This is what I am doing:

**1. Go to localhost:3000/suggestion_boxes/1/suggestions/new**

**2. The form app/views/suggestions/new.html.haml is displayed:**

```html
%header
  %h1.title
    = @suggestion_box.name + " Suggestion Box"
.main
  = form_for ([@suggestion_box, @suggestion_box.suggestions.build]) do |f|
    - if @suggestion.errors.any?
      #error_explanation
        %ul
          - @suggestion.errors.messages.values.each do |msg|
            = msg.to_sentence
    .field
      %br/
      = f.text_area :suggestion_message, type:"text", placeholder:"Drop a note in our suggestion box...", :rows => 6, :cols => 30
    .actions
      = f.submit "Continue"
```

**3. I enter text into the :suggestion_message field and click submit.  Then the app/views/suggestion_boxes/show.html.haml is displayed:**

```
%header
  %h1.title
    = @suggestion_box.name + " Suggestion Box"
%p#notice= notice
%p
  = link_to "Post a new suggestion", new_suggestion_box_suggestion_path(@suggestion_box)
%table
  %tr
    %th Message
    - @suggestions.each do |suggestion|
      %tr
        %td
          = suggestion.suggestion_message
```

**Here, however, while a flash message is displayed that the suggestion was successfully submitted, the suggestion_message tables is blank.**

This is what I get when I query the database for suggestions for this suggestion box:

```
Suggestion Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "suggestions".* FROM "suggestions" WHERE
"suggestions"."suggestion_box_id" = 1 => [#<Suggestion id: 1, suggestion_message: nil, created_at: "2013-06-04 15:49:58", updated_at: "2013-06-04 15:49:58", anonymous_suggestion: nil, member_id: nil, suggestion_box_id: 1>,
```

#]

Any ideas as to why the suggestion message is nil even though it appears it is being saved?

Thanks so much for any help!

**Snippets from files that might be needed to answer this. I've only included what I thought would be the relevant portions**

**SuggestionBox Model:**

```rb
class SuggestionBox < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name , :suggestions_attributes
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :suggestions, :dependent => :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :suggestions
end
```

**Suggestion Model:**

```rb
class Suggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :suggestion_message, :anonymous_suggestion
  belongs_to :suggestion_box
end
```

**routes.rb**

```rb
SuggestionBoxApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :invites, :organizations, :users, :sessions, :password_resets

  resources :suggestion_boxes do
    resources :suggestions
  end
end
```

**Suggestions Controller**

```rb
class SuggestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @suggestion_box = SuggestionBox.find(params[:suggestion_box_id])
    @suggestion = @suggestion_box.suggestions.build

    flash[:error] = "Sorry, no suggestion box found with the id #{:id}." and return unless @suggestion_box

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @suggestion }
    end
  end

  def create
    @suggestion_box = SuggestionBox.find(params[:suggestion_box_id])
    @suggestion = @suggestion_box.suggestions.new

    respond_to do |format|
      if @suggestion.save
        format.html { redirect_to suggestion_box_path(@suggestion_box), notice: 'Suggestion was successfully submitted.' }
        format.json { render json: @suggestion, status: :created }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @suggestion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**SuggestionBox Controller**

```rb
  class SuggestionBoxesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @suggestion_box = SuggestionBox.find(params[:id])
      @suggestions = @suggestion_box.suggestions.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @suggestions }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use the nested form, since you only create suggestion?

```
= form_for @suggestion do |f|
```

Everything else should be left without changes and it should work.

BTW, since you don't use nested attributes, you don't need neither `accepts_nested_attributes_for :suggestions`, nor `attr_accessible :suggestions_attributes` in your `SuggestionBox` model.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I don't need accepts_nested_attributes.  Re. use of a nested form, it would seem to me to make sense to nest suggestions within suggestion boxes, for one to allow for easily generating semantically meaningful URLs, and to also prevent the need for having to select a suggestion box when adding a new selection.  However, if those are not good reasons, or having nested resources in general is bad, I will explore approaching this without having nested resources.